# What controls the RAM voltage value?

Tags: memory, motherboard, power-supply

Quite simply, is the RAM module responsible for generating its own operating voltage or does it just run at whatever voltage the motherboard is providing?

I am imagining that it could either communicate its need to the motherboard which regulates to that voltage, or internally switches to generate the required voltage from whatever source voltage it has access to.

If the motherboard supplies a fixed voltage, what limits are there on compatibility in the 1.35-1.5V range? i.e. 1.5V supply to 1.35V RAM and 1.35V to 1.5V RAM.

Comment: For (almost all?) memory the motherboard supplies the power and sets the voltage. The timing and voltage may be chosen based on the information stored on modern DIMMs. But for regular PC memory (e.g. DDR 1/2/3) the voltage is supplied by the motherboard.

Comment: RAM consumes but doesn't generate electricity.

Comment: @Tyson when I say 'to generate the required voltage' I don't mean it creates its own electricity, I just mean it develops a voltage level by selectively consuming the voltage available to it from the motherboard.